# How can I make this overflow div expand to fill up page height?

Tags: html, css

Here's an example that goes halfway there:
http://jsfiddle.net/gt9vz4qk/1/

CSS: `#content {background-color: #fdd; overflow: auto; height: 70vh;}`

HTML:

```
<button>Hello</button>
<div id="content">
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
</div>
<input>
```

Using relative size units like `vh` helps, but I feel like I'm missing something really basic. As you can see, if you resize the window or even the splitter on the jsfiddle website far down, the other elements start compressing and a second scrollbar pops up. The only scrollbar should be the overflow one.

Another way to think about this is that I want the top elements to take up as much space as they need, the bottom elements to take as much space as they need, and anything else should be taken up by the central element.

Comment: this link seems helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2015/02/20/filling-the-remaining-height-of-a-container-while-handling-overflow-in-css.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) solution:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  background-color: #fdd;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Hello</button>
</div>
<div id="content">
  A<br>
A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>
</div>
<div>
  <input>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/81r3ndq4/)